# Can somebody explain this for loop definition to me I found in Hashicorp's immutable radix tree package?

Tags: for-loop, go

So, I've been writing Go for some years now, and while I know there is more to the for loop than the "usual" day-to-day case, this, I just don't quite get what is going on.

I mean, I can use it, but I don't get it.

```
for key, _, ok := it.Next(); ok; key, _, ok = it.Next()
```

It is from the immutable radix tree package here: https://github.com/hashicorp/go-immutable-radix.

I actually ask, because to retrieve the data I put in the tree, I have altered the code slightly () _ to blob), but now I am not sure if I should do the same in the second part.

```
for key, blob, ok := it.Next(); ok; key, _, ok = it.Next()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop starts with calling `it.Next()`, and continues as long as `ok` is true. `ok` is reset with `it.Next()` at the end of every loop. At each iteration, the loop also sets `key`.

Your modification sets `blob` at the initialization, but it never sets `blob` again. For all iterations, `blob` will have the first value it got from `it.Next()`. It is likely that you should set `blob` at the last condition of the loop as well, so you can get the `blob` for the next element.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense now. :)